# Retrieve specific JSON key from subcategory

Tags: ios, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm retrieving data only once from the server as JSON on my TableView and it is working fine. I couldn't print a specific subject from the JSON.

For example according to my JSON I just want to print the name's of the `Dining Room` or `Coffees` without `Bedroom`. How I can make that?

I can only print the whole name's of subcategory > products(names) with my code.

Code:

```
-(void)getJSON{

NSString *string = BaseURLString;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    _dic  = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

    for (NSDictionary *dict in [_dic objectForKey:@"categories"]) {

        if ([[dict valueForKey:@"sub_category"]  isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            [_arraySubCategory addObject:[[[dict valueForKey:@"sub_category"] valueForKey:@"products"] valueForKey:@"name"]];

        }

    }
```

My JSON Data:

```
Array
(
[categories] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => 100
                [name] => Shop By Room
                [sub_category] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [category_id] => 72
                                [name] => BEDROOM
                                [sub_category] => 0
                                [product_total] => 11
                                [products] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 138
                                                [name] => Jewellery  Holder
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 139
                                                [name] => Jewellery Holder
                                            )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [category_id] => 67
                                [name] => DINING ROOM
                                [sub_category] => 0
                                [product_total] => 73
                                [products] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 248
                                                [name] => Amuse
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 239
                                                [name] => Amuse
                                            )

                                            )
                                            .
                                            .
                                            .
       [1] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => 101
                [name] => Drink
                [sub_category] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [category_id] => 103
                                [name] => Coffees 
                                [sub_category] => 0
                                [product_total] => 14
                                [products] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 229
                                                [name] => Cafe1
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 233
                                                [name] => Cafe2

                                            )
```

Comment: What do `Dining Room` and `Coffees` have in common that `Bedroom` doesn't share?

Comment: It has the same things. I just want to learn how to get the name under the  `BEDROOM` or `Coffees` ? @IanMacDonald

Comment: Please describe the output that you desire given the JSON input you have already provided.

Comment: @IanMacDonald For example I want this output `Amuse` two times and `(Cafe1&Cafe2)`. Is this what you are asking me?

Comment: I'm confused about your "without `Bedroom`" requirement. Can you please provide a complete output that you expect?

Comment: Ok Let me make is simple how I can get the output of the `Coffees > products > name` ? which result in Cafe1 and Cafe2 @IanMacDonald

Comment: Your notation (whatever you call it) is barely comprehensible.  It would be better to present the pure JSON.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm sorry for using that type of printing JSON. I just wanted to show it more clear.

Comment: Well, it's not clear at all.  It's so garbled that I see no point in attempting to decipher it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not sure specifically what you're asking. It looks like you only want to print out the values from within `Coffees`. Just skip categories and subcategories that don't match the criteria you want by using `if (...) continue;`.

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in [_dic objectForKey:@"categories"]) {

    if (![dict[@"name"] isEqualToString:@"Drink"]) continue;

    for (NSDictionary *subcategory in [dict valueForKey:@"sub_category"])
    {

        if (![subcategory[@"name"] isEqualToString:@"Coffees"]) continue;

        for (NSDictionary *product in subcategory[@"products"]) {
            [_arraySubCategory addObject:product[@"name"]];
        }

    }

}
```

You should also be aware that what you have posted as JSON is **not** valid JSON. This appears to be a `print_r` from PHP.

Comment: It works...  Yes, sorry for using that type of print.